# PowerShell File Conversion

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I'm on to the next bit of fun with powershell and am trying to convert some files over to .csv files. Im trying to get all the files in my test2 directory with the extension .log and convert them over to .csv with a Null as a delimiter. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Get-ChildItem c:\test2\*.log | Export-Csv c:\test2\ -Delimiter "`0"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You just want to rename the file as a CSV?

Comment: You have to tell us what is wrong before we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Post what your file looks like before conversion and what you want it to look like after conversion.

Comment: ok, my file looks like this:  12:26:46 562.272    001/446/CCR446 ::proc_reading(CR-S4-IN       ) anz_bc (204/205)..
12:26:46 562.356    001/446/CCR446 ::proc_reading(CR-S4-IN  ) READ with the extension of .log and what I thought I was doing was converting that file over to a csv file. That was my goal. :-)

Comment: Dont add stuff like that as a comment, it's totally unreadable. Edit your original post and format it.

Comment: Also, are you really on PS v1? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Well they are still running XP here. :-)

Comment: PowerShell v2 is [available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) even for XP.

Answer (score 0):

Get-ChildItem is going to get you a directory list (fileinfo objects) - not the content of the files.  You'll need to use Get-Content to actually get the content of the logs, then you'll need to parse those log files, create Powershell objects from the parsed data, and then export those ojbects to csv.

Comment: Ok Ill try to do that.